# How can I define an area to be printed when the user clicks print on my web page?

Tags: html, css

I have a web page with headers and a side menu. On the right is a content area.

When a user clicks print or CTRL P I would like the user to be able to print off only the contents of the content area.

How can I do this without using any jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with css media queries alone with no javascript.

Without seeing your page it's hard to give a concrete example, but here's a start:

```
@media print {
#header {
    display: none;
}
}
```

You basically define what you want to display and how you want it to look in print in the media query and it should work in all modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this using CSS... Probably the simplest thing to do would be to add a media query to your existing CSS or to a style tag in the head of your html. To add the media query to the head of your document, add the following after the title tag (of course your style ids will differ):

```
<style>
@media print {

 #headerStyle {display:none;}
 #sideMenuStyle {display:none;}
 #contentStyle {width:100%;}

}
</style>
```

Another way is to add a separate 'Print" CSS link. This should be added after all of your other linked CSS or Style tags. Something like the following is pretty standard:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
```

Answer (score 0):

use easy javascript

`var foo = document.getElementById("containerID").innerHTML; //get contents that you want to print out
document.write(); //erases whole document
document.write(foo);`

the code above will take code from a certain area, delete everything, and then overwrite the document with the code you duplicated. worked for me =)